# How give information to a single page product

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Router

```
function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
        <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Main />}/>
        <Route exact path='/products/:productId' render={(props) => <Product />}/>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

and in the main page

```
function Main() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/products/get").then((p) => {
            setProducts(p.data)
        })
      }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Productos</h2>
            <div className="store">
            {products.reverse().map((p) => {
                let ref = `/products/${p.idProducts}`
                return <a href={ref}>
                    <div className="product">
                        <b>{p.name}</b><br/><i>${p.value}</i>
                    </div></a> })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And i want to get in my Product page the information of which product was selected (i just need the p.idProducts of the product selected in the Main page)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You want to know how to reference the `productId` from the url?

Comment: When i click in the <a>, i want to give to the <Product /> the p.idProducts of the product that i clicked. So i can display the Product page having the id of the product.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for this:

```
const { productId } = useParams();
```